# Delete rows in a table using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a table that creates new rows automatically after an `onclick` event. Also the code create a button that delete the rows when it's clicked.

The problem that I can't solve it's when I click for the second time the 'add row onclick event' I get two copies of the same row.

Thank you in advance for anyone can help me, here below you can find the code:

```
function deleteRow(r) {
  var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
  document.getElementById("orderedProductsTbl").deleteRow(i);
}

//this function manipulates DOM and displays content of our shopping cart
var shoppingCart = [];        
function displayShoppingCart(){
  var orderedProductsTblBody=document.getElementById("orderedProductsTblBody");
  //ensure we delete all previously added rows from ordered products table
  while(orderedProductsTblBody.rows.length>0) {
    orderedProductsTblBody.deleteRow(0);
  }

  //variable to hold total price of shopping cart
  var cart_total_price=0;
  //iterate over array of objects
  for(var product in shoppingCart){
    //add new row      
    var row=orderedProductsTblBody.insertRow();
    //add button
    var removeRow=document.createElement("Button");
    //set up button
    removeRow.innerHTML= "Delete"; 
    removeRow.setAttribute("onClick", "deleteRow(this)");                
    //create four cells for product properties 
    var cellName = row.insertCell(0);
    var cellDescription = row.insertCell(1);
    var cellPrice = row.insertCell(2);
    var cellDelete = row.insertCell(3);
    cellPrice.align="center";
    cellDescription.align ="right";
    cellDelete.align="right";
    cellName.height="40"
    cellPrice.height="40";
    cellDescription.height="40";
    cellDelete.height="40"
    //fill cells with values from current product object of our array
    cellName.innerHTML = shoppingCart[product].Name;
    cellDescription.innerHTML = shoppingCart[product].Description;
    cellPrice.innerHTML = shoppingCart[product].Price;
    cellDelete.appendChild( removeRow );
    cart_total_price+=shoppingCart[product].Price;     
  }
  //fill total cost of our shopping cart 
  document.getElementById("cart_total").innerHTML=cart_total_price;
}

function AddtoCart(name,description,price){
  //Below we create JavaScript Object that will hold three properties you have mentioned:    Name,Description and Price
  var singleProduct = {};
  //Fill the product object with data
  singleProduct.Name=name;
  singleProduct.Description=description;
  singleProduct.Price=price;
  //Add newly created product to our shopping cart 
  shoppingCart.push(singleProduct);
  //call display function to show on screen
  displayShoppingCart();
}
```

Comment: just advice: create a working https://jsfiddle.net/ example to help others to help you =)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36514870/how-to-delete-a-row-in-a-table-using-jquery/36515092#36515092 check this link. May be u'll get the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `AddtoCart` you add element to array `shoppingCart`, but when you remove row you just remove DOM elements, but information about your item is still in that array.

So you have to remove it from array too:

```
function deleteRow(r) {
    var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    document.getElementById("orderedProductsTbl").deleteRow(i);
    shoppingCart.splice(i, 1); //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-to-remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript
}
```

**EDIT**

And this fix won't help you with problem with adding same products every time. So you can clear `shoppingCart` array every time you call `displayShoppingCart` or rewrite your algorithm to don't use array for storing product infos in it.

Comment: Dear Slavik, thank you for your quick reply! I tryed to add your edited code to mine but i have the some problem again. Should I have to rewrite my code? Thank you for your help!

Comment: @FedericoCurtoni try to insert `shoppingCart = []` at the end of `displayShoppingCart` and don't use previous fix `shoppingCart.splice(i, 1);`

Comment: thank you! Now it works perfectly! Thank you again, have a great day!

Comment: @FedericoCurtoni but think about why it works and rewrite your code, please =)

Comment: I think because you "clear" the array and reset it? Obviously I will keep learning about JS and improve my code :)